# eregi_replace("[\]",'',$data) -- what does this line do?

Tags: php, regex

In the latest phpmailer example file, there's the following line:

```
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
```

As I'm not really good in regular expressions, I can't figure out what the above does and whether I need to use it when I write my own block of data (`$body`). Could anyone help me figure this out?

**EDIT**

I really copied it properly. Here is a whole chunk of code from the original phpmailer example file, completely untouched:

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
```

Comment: Yes, copied directly from their file, didn't touch it at all.

Comment: @mario: it doesn't, because that backslash escapes following ]

Comment: @genesis-φ: `eregi` uses POSIX regex syntax, which happens to allow this edge case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code is removing all backslashes from `$body`.

Though it may look a little odd at first glance, the regex *is* correct. The backslash isn't a metacharacter when it's inside brackets in a POSIX regex.

There's all sorts of problems with this code anyway, though, especially since it's supposed to be an example:

- It uses one of the deprecated `ereg` (or POSIX) family of regex functions. Half-recent PHP examples should pretty much all be using the `preg` (Perl-compatible) family instead.
- It uses case-insensitive matching (the `i` in `eregi`) even though it's not matching against any letters, so case is irrelevant.
- Most importantly, the actual purpose of the replacement is unclear.  I can only guess that this is a misguided attempt to account for PHP's [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) feature that automatically adds backslashes to all sorts of things.

  To be clear, this code is **not** a proper way to deal with magic quotes, since it will remove *all* backslashes from `$body`, even "real" ones present in the original input. The [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function is intended for exactly this use case. Or, since the example deals with reading from a file, you could simply [turn off magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php).

Answer (score 1):

The code removes all backslahses.

Just try out the code [**on some sample input**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RpIdj6).

I'm not sure why `eregi` was chosen, since it and its brethren have been deprecated. Better to use [**`preg_replace()`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TqPu55).

Note that `eregi_replace()` and `preg_replace()` have different usage rules. The first uses the POSIX regex extension while the later uses the PCRE functions. Here's a [**list of the differences**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php), which are what makes understanding your code difficult if you assume `preg_replace()` syntax.

These all do the same thing:

```
eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);  \\ Remove backslashes with POSIX regexes

preg_replace("[\\\]",'',$body);   \\ Remove backslashes with PCRE regexes
preg_replace("/[\\\]/",'',$body); \\ Ditto
preg_replace("/\\\/",'',$body);   \\ Ditto
preg_replace("*\\\*",'',$body);   \\ Ditto
```

[**Further**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) [**reading**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).

Answer (score -1):

This `"[\]"` means that you are escaping the left-pointed tag `]`...

Comment: Your answer does not make sense. What about the left bracket then ? Does is not need to also be escaped?

Comment: I was way of, the bracket is frames for the match.