# Alternative for ergi_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)
>   [eregi_replace(“[\]”,'',$data) — what does this line do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706918/eregi-replace-data-what-does-this-line-do)

I am using phpmailer and it is using eregi_replace, I am trying to update this, would this be correct, I am not sure if I have the `/i` in the right place?.

```
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
```

would become:

```
$body = preg_replace("[\]",''/i,$body);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex removes all `\` from the body. It is not necessary to have that case insensitive, since `\` does not have case. You would write that regex like:

```
$body = preg_replace('/\\\\/i', $body);
```

Not that you do not need the `i` as I said because their is no difference between a case insensitive and a case sensitive match here. Also note that the actual regular expression is just `\`. The `/` are delimiters and you need four backslashes, because they are in a PHP string so they become two literal backslashes `\\` which is needed because the expression `/\/` is invalid since the backslash escapes the end delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

No. You'd have to write `preg_replace('/\\/i', '', $body)`. This is assuming, of course, that you'd like to remove all backslashes inside the body.

Comment: You have to type the backslash four times when you want to use it in regex literally.

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = preg_replace("/[\\]/i","",$body);
```

Comment: I get this error when I try using this  >>

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 3 in C:\server2go\server2go\htdocs\chandlers\components\com_jumi\views\application\view.html.php(38) : eval()'d code on line 9

Comment: Ah yes, of course - sorry, use \\\\ in the square brackets