# PHPMailer - Does body have to come from a file now?

Tags: phpmailer

I've been using PHPMailer successfully for a couple of years. I just refreshed my PHPMailer class from their github site, and now my server throws 500 errors. I tracked down the problem to this line (simplified for this post):

```
$mail->Body = "<p>Hello World</p>";
```

All of the example that I see on the [worxware website](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp) these days show the body of the email being read from a file like this:

```
$body = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

I also tried modifying my code to use the MsgHTML syntax, but I still have the same result:

```
$body = "<p>Hello World</p>";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

I can't imagine that it matters whether this body gets populated from a file or from a local variable, but nothing that I try works. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Kindly refer this link it will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706918/eregi-replace-data-what-does-this-line-do

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but I still get the same result. I'll update my post to show it.

Comment: None of the examples on github use `eregi_*` functions - they have been deprecated for years, so I don't know where you got that from. Why are you even doing that anyway? PHPMailer doesn't care where you get your content from, so long as it ends up in `Body`.

Comment: @Synchro - I was referring to examples found here: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp. Maybe they aren't 'official' examples? I thought that they were. My mistake, and my apologies.

Comment: That site's not been updated for a long time - It's never actually lived there (it was on SourceForge, then Google Code, then Github). Everything is now on Github, though there are a zillion other sites that say lots of random (often wrong!) stuff about PHPMailer!

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately, if I Google 'phpmailer example', my first four results are from that site.

Answer (score 1):

$output = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"",$output);

try this

Comment: That worked. I wonder why that wasn't anywhere in any of their examples. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: It's not in the examples because that's a pretty strange thing to do - most people want line breaks in their messages!

Comment: It turns out that this isn't the solution to my issue. I'm getting very eratic results no matter what I do. Some attempts work, some don't, and I still can't figure out what makes any differences. To make sure that nobody else is mislead thinking that this is what they should do, I need to retract my acceptance of this answer. Sorry about that @kailash.

Comment: @Synchro - you are right. I was very surprised that this 'worked'. It turns out that it really didn't. Just a coincidence masking something else. Sorry for the confusion.